# How to control CAKeyframeAnimation with touch gesture?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, path, core-animation, caemitterlayer

I have a `CAEmitterLayer` animated along a bezier path (closed form, like an '8', out of four control points) with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Now I want to control the animation by a slide of a touch-finger along (but not necessarily on) the path. How is this possible and is this even possible?

Comment: You mean emitting particles from where the user is dragging their finger? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I am very new to objective-c and have no idea how to lead an animation (let it be a CAEmitterLayer or an UIImageView or layer) along a path with a finger touch movement. I would be happy with every little hint...
I tried to use a mask-image which I layed over the path that told me of the finger was on or besides the path but then the particles also emit besides the path.

Comment: Why not just change the position f the emitter layer to the position of the users finger by setting the position property? Getting the point where the user is not hard.

Comment: I need to have to emitter on the defined path of the KeyframeAnimation. but the finger should be allowed to only be near the path to controll the movement on the path.

Comment: So the emitter will only ever be _on_ the path but the finger should be close? You want to know how to calculate where on the path the emitter should be? Like calculating the closest point on the path from where the users finger is?

Comment: this would be one possible way. the other way would be to 'scrub' the animation along the path like you control a movie frame by frame back and/or forth.

Comment: +1 would be interested in knowing if this is possible

Answer (score 1):

Make a `CGpoint click;` variable to remember your initial "drag" point, then create a local `NSEvent` handler...

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: NSMouseMovedMask
                                             | NSLeftMouseDownMask 
                                      handler:^(NSEvent *e) {
    if ( e.type == NSLeftMouseDown ) click = e.locationInWindow;
    else "yourDelta" = click - e.locationInWindow;  // pseudoCode 
    return e;
}];
```

"yourDelta" is the offset of that initial point from the current location...  you could also achieve similar results with scroll events, by monitoring `NSEventScrollWheelMask`... and looking at the `e.deltaX` and `e.deltaY` values.

Edit:  I'm not as familiar with event handling on iOS.. but the same technique could be applied with normal event handlers... ie.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)e {
    click = [e locationInView:_yourView];       
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)e {
    "yourDelta" = click - [e locationInView:_yourView];  // pseudoCode 
}
```

As to "seeking" your animation..  One possible way is to simply `[layer addAnimation:theNewAnimation]`, using your previous `toValue`'s, but instead of basing the `fromValue`'s of 0, or your model `layer`... use your `layer.presentationLayer` values instead?  It is hard to say without seeing the full content of your `CAKeyframeAnimation`.

Comment: This being tagged with 'cocoa-touch' I assumed the OP was looking for a way to do this on an iOS device.
Is there way to 'seek' the CAKeyframeAnimation based on the delta value?